# ScrollMagic не может работать с GSAP?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gsap, scrollmagic

Всем привет, я пытаюсь научиться анимации по скроллу и хочу попробовать для этого ScrollMagic совместно с GSAP, но у меня не получается даже скомпилировать свой файл. Я использую laravel.mix для webpack, в качестве сборщика проекта.

Я попробовал поискать ответ в интернете и единственное, что я нашел: нужно, что бы gsap подключался до scrollmagic, собственно, у меня так и есть вроде как..

Что я делаю не так? И как это исправить, что бы все заработало?

Мой javascript выглядит так:

```
import {TimelineMax} from 'gsap';
import ScrollMagic from 'ScrollMagic';
import 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators';
import 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap';

let tl = new TimelineMax();
let firstMan = document.getElementById('first-man');
tl.to(firstMan, 1, {x:'-100', y:'70'});

let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: '100%', // resposive duration in %
    offset: 0, // offset trigger position by 100px
    triggerElement: '#firstTrigger', // what will trigger scene
    triggerHook: 0
});

scene.addIndicators({name: 'bla bla'});
scene.setTween(tl);
scene.addTo(controller);
```

Так выглядят мои зависимости для проекта:
[image: скриншот файла package.json]

Но когда я пытаюсь запустить этот код, он выдает мне следующую ошибку:
[image: скриншот ошибки компиляции]

Окей, я попробовал и то, что он попросил:
[image: ошибка npm при попытке установить модули, которые он попросил]

Comment: А пробовал снести папку `node_modules` и потом накатить заново `npm i`?

Comment: А если просто сделать npm i, то это не тоже самое? 
Сейчас попробую..

Comment: Нет, ничего не поменялось(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя n-времени поисков решения проблемы, найден ответ [здесь](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/665)

Установил imports-loader и внес изменения в подключения:

```
import { TimelineMax, TweenMax, Linear } from 'gsap';
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'

import 'imports-loader?define=>false!scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators'
import 'imports-loader?define=>false!scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap'
```